# JqGrid Search Options: toolbarsearch vs standard search window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, razor

I want to allow users to filter each column using only one sopt setting.  But for more advanced searching (for power users) I want to allow them to use the built in search button but I want to override the individual column search options for the ones listed in odata.  For example I want my users to only have ['eq'] but I want power user to be able to choose from odata. But the search options in the search window only use the ones associated with the column definition.

```
 oGridtxtsopt = ['cn'];
 oGriddtesopt = ['eq'];
 oGridnumsopt = ['eq'];
 oGridselsopt = ['eq'];
 oGridFile = '@ViewBag.GridType';
 oGridSortColumn = "FirstName";
 oGridColNames = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'E-mail Address', 'Date', 'Gender', 'State list', 'Rate', 'Age', 'Phone Number', ''];
 oGridColModel =
        [
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 110, searchoptions: {sopt:['eq','bw']}},

            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 110, searchoptions: { sopt: oGridtxtsopt} },

            { name: 'EmailAddress', index: 'EmailAddress', width: 250, searchoptions: { sopt: oGridtxtsopt }, formatter: 'email' },

            { name: 'HireDate', index: 'HireDate', width: 80, align: "center", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
                searchoptions: { sopt: oGriddtesopt, dataInit: amiDatePicker} },

            { name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', width: 55, align: "center", stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("amiLookup")?' + $.param({ lookup: 'GENDER' })} },

            { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 110, align: "center", stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("amiLookup")?' + $.param({ lookup: 'STATES' })} },

            { name: 'Rate', index: 'Rate', width: 45, align: "right", searchoptions: { sopt: oGridnumsopt }, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: " %"} },

            { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 30, align: "center", searchoptions: { sopt: oGridnumsopt }, formatter: 'integer' },

            { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 95, align: "center", searchoptions: { sopt: oGridtxtsopt }, formatter: amiPhoneFormatter },

            { name: 'Action', index: 'Action', width: 40, align: "center", sortable: false, search: false, formatter: amiActionFormatter }
        ];

        oGridSearch = "endeavourSearch";
        oGridName = "endeavourGrid";
        oGridPager = "endeavourGridPager";

 $('#' + oGridName).jqGrid
        ({              

            recordtext: oGridFile + " Found - {2}",
            emptyrecords: "No " + oGridFile + " Found",
            loadtext: "Searching " + oGridFile + "...",
            pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: oGridColNames,
            colModel: oGridColModel,
            recreateFilter: true,
            rowNum: 15,
            mtype: "GET",
            rowList: [15, 30, 50, 100],
            pager: '#' + oGridPager,
            sortname: oGridSortColumn,
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: "100%",
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: false,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: false,
            hidegrid: false,
            clearfooter: true,
            caption: oGridFile + " List",
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }

        })

        .filterToolbar(
            {
                stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, closeOnEscape: true 
            })



        .navGrid('#' + oGridPager,
            {
                edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: true,
                searchtitle: "Search using advanced search options",
                searchtext: "Advanced Search"
            },
            { }, // edit
            { }, // add
            { }, // delete
            { 
                closeOnEscape: true, 
                multipleSearch: true, 
                closeAfterSearch: true,
                closeAfterReset: true,
                caption: "Endeavour Advanced Search",
                Find: "Search",
                Reset: "Cancel",
                odata: ['equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal', 'greater', 'greater or equal', 'begins with', 'does not begin with', 'is in', 'is not in', 'ends with', 'does not end with', 'contains', 'does not contain'],
                groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR", text: "any"}],
                matchText: "    Find",
                rulesText: " matches"

            }, // Search 
            {} // view
            ) ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place on the first place (as the first element) of `sopt` the option which you want to use in the `filterToolbar`. For example `en` for all select elements (`stype: 'select'`) and `cn` or `bw` for the rest (default `stype: 'text'`). You can additionally use `defaultSearch` parameter of `filterToolbar` which will be used if no search `sopt` option are defined inside of the `searchoptions`.