# in jqgrid, is there anyway to support greaterthan and lessthan in the toolbar search

Tags: jquery, filter, jqgrid

i know i can support this by using the advanced search but people are finding it a bit cumbersome.  It would be cool if i could support something like this right in the toolbar search:

```
< 100
```

or

> 11-Dec-2010

by just entering this string above in the toolbar textbox.  is there anyway for jqgrid to support this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define **one compare operation for the column** used in the searching toolbar (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341946/jqgrid-search-options-toolbarsearch-vs-standard-search-window/5342217#5342217)). If the first operation in the `sopt` array of [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options) for the corresponding column is **'lt'** or **'le'** the operation will be used for the filtering:

```
searchoptions: {sopt:['lt','eq','ne','le',...] }
```

The full set of values from `sopt` will be used for the "Adnanced Searching"

Comment: @Oleg - this is a little implicit . . is there anyway to detect that someone entered "<" and change the operation from "cn" (my normal default operation to "lt".  this will let me have contains by default but if someone put in "< 100" it will then do a less than filter

Comment: @ooo: No. It seems me too complex in the implementation. What I suggested is in my opinion the only simple solution of the problem. If you want use select elements in the searching toolbar you have to define `searchoptions: {sopt:`. If you don't do this select option "No" will filter additionally "Not really" for example because "begin with" or "contain" will be used and "Not really" begin with "No". Both filter toolbar and advanced searching use **the same** `sopt` array only filter toolbar use the first element and advanced searching - all. So my suggestion really solve your problem.

Comment: @Oleg - i think i will basically just try to do that translation on the server side  to detect "<" or ">" and run my greater or lessthan filter code instead of contains . . a little hacky but i think the ability to stick < and > in front of dates and number columns is quite useful and quick . . .

Comment: @ooo: To tell the truth I don't like the idea. You will produce a special syntax. The user which use you problem can not work intuitive he have to study the syntax. One more problem is if the text itself has "<". I find better (only if the feature which you ask is **really needed**) to extend in any way the user interface and add additional combobox with the compare operation "le", "lt", "bw", ... above the search toolbar. If user change the compare operation you just change the order in the `sopt` array. The implementation can be not one line of code, but it can work and be flexible.

Comment: @Oleg - i like your idea of having an additional combobox with the operator but we are starting to get as slow as the multiple advance search at that point.  it might be a compromise.  if i wanted to follow your suggestion, how can i capture when the user hits enter so i am apply the operation into postdata ??

Comment: @ooo: Your last suggestion seems me better. After the searching filter have filled the `postData` and before if trigger `"reloadGrid"` it call [beforeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). So inside the function you can make any modifications of the `postData`.

Comment: @Oleg - cool .  i will add the conversion to greater and less than in the beforeSearch code