# Does jqGrid cmTemplate option interfere with filtertoolbar?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The grid with the options below with the  filtertoolbar works fine when you comment out the 'sopt' options but not with the options uncommented
I put up a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pwachira/9awcC/#base). In my real grid I have cmTemplate specifed outside all my grids in a `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{})` -it still causes the same problem

```
$('#Table').jqGrid({
    cmTemplate: {
        searchoptions: {
           // sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] //un comment this line then run again and try to use filtere to see the difference
        }
    },
    datatype: 'local',
    data: [{
        Code: 'code1'},
    {
        Code: 'code2'},
    {
        Code: 'code3'}],
    colNames: ['Code'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'Code',
        index: 'Code'}],
    pager: '#Pager'
}).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOnEnter: false,
    defaultSearch: 'cn'
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems in the code. If you set

```js
cmTemplate: {
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }
}
```

you add `searchoptions.sopt` in all columns which don't has the setting. Toolbar filtering can use only one searching operation per column. jqGrid uses `defaultSearch` parameter of `filterToolbar` for the searching, but to be able to have another searching operation for some columns it can be overwritten from the first operation of `searchoptions.sopt` array (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360780/315935) for example).
It is very important feature because which really required.

So including `searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }` option in *all* columns overwrite practically the option `defaultSearch: 'cn'` of `filterToolbar` to `defaultSearch: 'eq'`. Exactly in the way work the demo which you posted.

Comment: so if I have 'cn' as tha 1 st option in sopt the filter works, I guess I can live with that

Comment: @chohi: It is so. You should understand why the rule with `searchoptions.sopt[0]` is require. If you for example have `formatter: "select", editoption: {value:":All;1:one;11:elf"}`. It produces dropdown in searching toolbar. If you would use 'cn' operation from `defaultSearch: 'cn'` for the column you will produce : "contain 1" operation in case the user choose "one" option. So instead of selecting only the values having '1' one will find '11' too and the filtered grid will display rows having both "one" and "elf". To fix the problem one have to define `sopt` where `searchoptions.sopt[0]='eq'`